# Is the following question eligible for the Windows 8 challenge?

Tags: support, windows-8-challenge

This is a particularly specific question, but I hope someone can help. I posted this question five days ago about Windows 8. I had no idea about the challenge, but now I'm wondering if it was posted a few hours too soon to qualify for it? Seems damned annoying if that's the case :(

Question: [Aero Glass/Transparent window borders in Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/489853/is-there-a-way-to-make-windows-borders-transparent)

Can anyone tell me? Sorry for being dumb.

Thanks.

Comment: *The Windows 8 Challenge will run for three weeks, starting on Friday, Oct 19 5:00 PM UTC [...]*. Question posted around 11 AM that day, so, no.

Comment: But are all the site's times in UTC or what?

Comment: I think they're zulu, least if you hover over it.

Comment: @JohnnyW All the times on the site are in UTC. Terminology like "today", "yesterday" is used inconsistently though, for example sometimes meaning "the 24 hour period ending NOW" and sometimes meaning "the UTC day before today".

Comment: A related query to this - if you post an answer *during* the event to a question posted *before* the event, does that answer count?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its down to the tape, pretty much, but I'm guessing you posted just a little too early for it to count - it shows up when i do a user-tag search, but dosen't show up on your contest page, and its old enough that it should. Sorry to be the bearer of bad news.

Comment: Sob! That's pretty damned annoying.